# How can I get the index number of any column in an SQL database?

Tags: sql

SQL:

```
Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Password) From Student
```

Comment: MS SQL Server? or MySQL?

Comment: Relevant: [The column order is just a "cosmetic" thing we humans care about - to SQL Server, it's almost always absolutely irrelevant....There is no SQL command to define the column ordering.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1605167/5894241)

Comment: Why?  What are you trying to accomplish?  What problem are you trying to solve?  For what reason can you not simply look at the output and count?

Comment: Your edit indicates something completely different from before the edit. Please explain in words, not code, what you want and why.

Comment: I want to get Index number(row number) of any Column

Comment: That doesn't help a lot, I still don't know what you expect. What is this "index number"?

Comment: how can get position of a particular column in table.  like 150 column  in table and i want access password column through their position so how can i do ?

Comment: Please add this information to the question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most, but not all (I think Oracle is one which doesn't) database systems implemented the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` which you can query to get information about database objects. In order to get the `ordinal position` of a column in a table, you can use:

```
SELECT      C.ORDINAL_POSITION
FROM        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS C
WHERE       C.TABLE_NAME = 'Table'
        AND C.COLUMN_NAME = 'Password'
```

I can't help wonder why you need this information though...

Comment: Yes sir  I  found column number of 'Password' field